# Is there a client tool available for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, client

I need a window client tool like twitter to see updates to specific Stack Overflow questions in Firefox or in my system tray. Is there a free tool available?

Comment: Dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/a-desktop-app-for-the-so-family

Comment: Hey. I'm working currently on [Stack Overflow App](https://github.com/Maqsim/stackoverflow-app) and also you can watch my streams [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/max_diachenko/). Some activity is welcomed star project, share with your friend and watch my streams and we will build an awesome app with all you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt there is an "official" windows client but you should probably take a look at [StackApps](http://www.stackapps.com)  There will probably be something there.

In fact there is TweetDeck style app [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app+windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RSS feeds - each of the searches, tags, and questions have one (and use any of the RSS readers on your platform for notification).