# Any desktop client for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a client tool available for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63687/is-there-a-client-tool-available-for-stack-overflow)

It would be very good to have a desktop client for Stack Overflow.

Does any desktop client project exists?

Comment: Dupe - [Is there a client tool available for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63687/is-there-a-client-tool-available-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Also Dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/a-desktop-app-for-the-so-family

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no full-blown desktop client, because Stack Exchange API is read-only so far. However, check the **[StackApps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps)** site - you will find many interesting applications there.

**UPDATE**

The Stack Exchange API is no longer read-only.

[Stack Exchange API - Write Access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write)

> Starting with version 2.1, the Stack Exchange API provides limited
>   support for writing to sites in the Stack Exchange network. There are
>   a number of constraints imposed to prevent abuse and loss of quality
>   on Stack Exchange sites.